# Django recursive aggregates

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-queryset

Using django, lets say I have a model thats a Team model which has a foreign key to itself called grouped. I also have a model called Pen with a foreign key to a team.

```
class Team(Model):
    grouped = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        related_name='grouped_teams',
    )

class Pen(Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(
        Team,
        related_name='pens',
    )
    ink = IntegerField()
```

There are several teams and each have pens. Now lets say you take those several teams and add a new team which all of those teams point towards via grouped. This can happen many times with only some teams so that you end up with something resembling the following where only the original teams (the lowest level ones) have pens:

```
                                A-Team
                                  /\
                                 /  \
                                /    \
                               B      C
                              /\      7 pens
                             /  \    
                            /    \
                           /      \
                          D        E
                        4 pens     /\
                                  /  \
                                 /    \
                                /      \
                               F        G
                            5 pens      2 pens
```

Knowing only the A-Team, is there a way to aggregate the sum of ink on the pens?

self.grouped_teams.aggregate(Sum('pens__ink')) works nicely for one level but not more. Raw sql?

Comment: You could add your own recursive function to your model, something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725343/django-self-recursive-foreignkey-filter-query-for-all-childs, and do a sum over that

Comment: Thx @klasske. bit scary though when it could be quite a lot of recursion. im guessing that a raw sql query is the way to go but I haven't cracked it yet.