# Rendering and using self-referencing model objects in nested format without duplicates in Django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Hope you are doing well...

I have a little misunderstanding in using self-referencing model objects in html template.

**models.py**

```
class MyNumber(models.Model):
    has_bro = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    numb = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.numb
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    context = {
        'numbers': MyNumber.objects.all()
    }    
    return render(request, 'test_folder/test_file.html', context)
```

Let's say I have objects like 1 which has referencing objects too like 1.1 and 1.2. To make it complex let's add also more objects like 1.1.1 and 1.1.2 which are referencing to 1.1.

The question is how to get all objects in nested format using `<ul></ul>` HTML tag without duplicates, like:

```
* 1
   * 1.1
      * 1.1.1
      * 1.1.2
   * 1.2
```

So far, I am getting this result (below) with my little knowledge:

```
* 1
   * 1.1
   * 1.2
* 1.1
   * 1.1.1
   * 1.1.2
* 1.2
```

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you seek is not just operation with django model, that has a FK to itself. Seems like you need to implement some tree, which is not an easy technical task. Depending on your requirements such as desired performance, etc, you may want to implement your own solution or use already implemented ones. There was a goto solution before called django mptt, but seems like it's abandoned. Regardless on their github page(https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) they have useful links. This post will be good starting point for you to go - https://406.ch/writing/django-tree-queries/