# Self reference ForeignKey with comment/comment reply relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to implement replies to my comments and am not sure how self ForeignKey's work. Here's my `Comment` model.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    destination = models.CharField(default='1', max_length=12, blank=True)
    parent_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    reply = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
    comment_text = models.TextField(max_length=350, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.comment_text)
```

Right now this is how my initial comment (parent comment) view looks like:

```
def user_comment(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        comment = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
        ajax_comment = request.POST.get('text')
        id = request.POST.get('id')

        if comment.is_valid():
            comment = Comment.objects.create(comment_text=ajax_comment, destination=id, user=request.user)
            comment.save()
            username = str(request.user)
            return JsonResponse({'text': ajax_comment, 'username': username, 'id': comment.id})
```

so that just creates a regular instance of `Comment`. Now here's my attempt at a reply comment (seperate view):

```
def comment_reply(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        comment = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
        reply_text = request.POST.get('reply_text')
        id = request.POST.get('id')
        parent_id = request.POST.get('parent_id')
        parent = Comment.objects.get(id=parent_id)

        if comment.is_valid():
            comment = Comment.objects.create(comment_text=reply_text, destination=id,
                                             user=request.user, parent_id=parent_id, reply=parent)
            comment.save()
            username = str(request.user)
            return JsonResponse({'reply_text': reply_text, 'username': username})
```

is `reply=parent` the right way to create the reply `Comment` object? I'm struggling with how to connect the two. My template, which just renders parent comments looks like this:

```
    {% for i in comment_list %}
        <div class='comment_div' data-comment_id="{{ i.id }}">
            <div class="left_comment_div">
                <div class="username_and_votes">
                    <h3><a class='username_foreign'>{{ i.user }}</a></h3>
                </div>
                <br>
                <p>{{ i.comment_text }}</p>
            </div>
                <a class="reply">reply</a><a class="cancel_comment">cancel</a>
                <span><a class="comment_delete" data-comment_id="{{ i.id }}">x</a></span>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

So once I connect the parent comment and reply comment, how would it render in the template above?

Comment: Perhaps this might be helpful?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/4725343/2750819

Comment: Instead of `parent_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)` it should be `parent = models.ForeignKey("self", blank=True, null=True)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `reply` field just add parent field like below.

```
parent = models.ForeignKey("self", blank=True, null=True, related_name="comment_parent")
```

Adding comments:

```
if request.POST.get('parent_id'):
     parent = Comment.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('parent_id'))
     comment = Comment.objects.create(comment_text=reply_text, destination=id, user=request.user, parent=parent)
```