# Django - Models - Recursively retrieve parents of a leaf node

Tags: python, django

I have a User model class defined as follows:

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=35, unique=True,help_text="URI dell'utente che appare sul browser")
    team = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, verbose_name="Team")
    area = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, verbose_name="Area")
    line_manager = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True,related_name='parent')
```

**I would like to retrieve all the line_managers of a CustomUser.** 
Let's suppose I have:

```
A
-B 
 -C
```

where C is the leaf and B and A are the values I would like to retrieve.
How can I do in django?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django self-recursive foreignkey filter query for all childs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725343/django-self-recursive-foreignkey-filter-query-for-all-childs)

Comment: I saw that post but I was wondering whether there is a cleaner and moe efficient way (ie.directly making queries) to accomplish the same result

Comment: Okay, let's wait and see if someone comes up with a better solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have not tested this but it should work:

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=35, unique=True,help_text="URI dell'utente che appare sul browser")
    team = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, verbose_name="Team")
    area = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, verbose_name="Area")
    line_manager = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True,related_name='parent')

    def get_linemanagers(self):
        if self.line_manager is None:
            return CustomUser.objects.none()
        return CustomUser.objects.filter(pk=self.line_manager.pk) | self.line_manager. get_linemanagers()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: how could I write a similar function to do the contrary, that is retrieving all the descendants (not only the direct children) of a CustomUser?

Comment: I have tried it but I am getting a RecursionError: `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`